# After Create Luma Child Theme The Customer Login Register Not Working Also No Any Error Display in Magento 2.3.5

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, frontend, luma-theme

I Created Luma Chield Theam In That I over ride the Only Magent_Theme
in that customer login register not working
[image]

[image]

And Also Add To Cart Throw Me 404 like That

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you phtml file some in phtml file if you do not close the div properly so that kind oh issued occur